# factory pattern - with templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following in a 3rd party core header, which i would prefer not to touch:

```
template<typename Iterator_T>
struct Tree
{
    template<typename Node_T>
    struct TypedNode;

    struct AbstractNode
    {
        AbstractNode(Iterator_T t)
        {
            ...
        }

        template<typename Rule_T>
        TypedNode<Rule_T>* NewChild()
        {
            TypedNode<Rule_T>* ret = new TypedNode<Rule_T>(this);
            AddChild(ret);
            return ret;
        }

        template<typename T>
        TypedNode<T>* GetFirstTypedChild();
    };

    template<typename Node_T>
    struct TypedNode : AbstractNode
    {
        ...
    };

    template<typename Rule_T, typename ParserState_T>
    void CreateNode(ParserState_T& p)
    {
        current = current->template NewChild<Rule_T>();
    }
};

template<typename Node_T>
struct TreeBuilder
{
    Tree<Iterator_T> tree;

    template<typename Rule_T>
    void CreateNode()
    {
        tree.CreateNode<Rule_T>(*this);
    }
};
```

and would like to add a subclass of TypedNode to the tree with additional methods and members. Is there a clean way to do this without refactoring the original code? I think the crux of the issue is:
            TypedNode* ret = new TypedNode(this);

This looks like it could use a Factory, perhaps by specializing the TypedNode template instantiation and including the header before the base headers. Something like:

```
template<>
struct Tree<const char*>::TypedNode<SpecificRuleType>
{
    ...
};
```

But it fails complaining "too few template-parameter-lists". Probably something trivial but my <template-fu> is a bit rusty :>(. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `Tree` and `TypedNode` are templates, your specialization should be:

```
template<> // for Tree<...>
template<> // for TypedNode<...>
struct Tree<const char*>::TypedNode<SpecificRuleType>
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: One More Time.. the edit box timed out. <enter> insists on submitting the comment in this browser! 

Thanks - that did get around the error. Regrettably another promptly popped up complaining about:

current = current->template NewChild<Rule_T>(pos)

saying that it cannot convert Tree<const char*>::TypedNode<SpecificRuleType>* to Tree<const char*>::AbstractNode* in assignment. TypedNode is a subclass of AbstractNode, but perhaps this is because the first declaration of TypedNode does not specify that it inherits from AbstractNode.

Comment: Nevermind.. there is an alternative approach which avoids all of this template-fu. Even if i did get it working i suspect moving it to another compiler could be an Adventure and the problem is fairly trivial. Thanks for your help!